# When I open the modal view, the header image appears in front of modal, how do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: This is an picture of the issue]I have set up a function that will open a login modal view when The site logo is clicked.

The modal view opens correctly, but with three elements ignoring the rules of the modal code.

The two site logo images, and the site menu current tab appear above the modal and without being affected by the background opacity that shades the rest of the site.

I have tried to solve this my setting the z-index of the elements to correspond with where I would like them to appear, but this had no effect. 
As I am fairly inexperienced with coding I haven't been able to spot where I might be going wrong.

```js
/* Click the top left box to open modal */
```

```css
.input-txt {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: $blue;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(250, 250, 250, .4);
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  @include placeholder(lighten($blue, 10%));
  @include transition(background-color .5s ease-in-out);
  &: focus {
    background-color: darken($blue, 30%);
  }
}
p {
  font-size: 16px text-align: left;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 16px
}
/* CSS for modal */

/* Full-width input fields */

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}
/* Set a style for all buttons */

button {
  background-color: #1dacf9;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33%;
}
/* Extra styles for the cancel button */

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}
/* Center the image and position the close button */

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}
img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.container {
  padding: 6px;
}
span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
  /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 66%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  height: 66vh;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/* The Close Button (x) */

.close {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2% auto 95% auto;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Add Zoom Animation */

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#headerBackground {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
}
#TWLogo {
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
}
#Logo:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#Text {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 355px;
  height: 125px;
  transform: translateZ(30px);
  background-position: center;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

  <img id="headerBackground" src="siteImages/tiltchair.jpg">

  <img id="Logo" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" align="middle" src="siteImages/final.png" alt="Logo">

  <img id="Text" align="middle" src="siteImages/TWText.png" alt="Logo">







  <div id="id01" class="modal">

    <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="input-txt" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        <label><b>Password</b>
        </label>
        <input type="password" class="input-txt" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Remember me
      </div>


      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>

    </form>
  </div>
```

**(Note that I haven't imported my images to the fiddle as the affect is still visible without them)**

To activate the modal click the top left box.

I do hope someone on here can see where I'm going wrong as this issue has been bothering me for a couple days now!

Comment: Your jsfiddle link just links to jsfiddle.net (not an actual fiddle)

Comment: @Axel Thanks I changed it over now, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/a0ht7y51/

Comment: I am unable to see the problem you described in your fiddle.

Comment: @Armin If you click on the box in the top left, you will see that the container that says Logo appears over the top of the modal. This is what I'm having an issue with.

Comment: @Andrew On my side it looks fine. Text "Logo" is behind gray pop-up. Even if I add an image, pop-up is still hovering over everything.  Maybe I am missing your point.

Comment: @Armin Okay Im not sure why that would be, if you check the above picture I have added to the question then you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Andrew There is inconsistency in your code you posted here on this page, and the one on jsfiddle. The one on jsfiddle is working fine, and the one you posted here is the problem you described.

Comment: @Blackcoat77 The issue shows up with both on my end, any idea what could be going on?

Comment: @Andrew Please check my answer, I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Just close `</div>` with id header and it it should work:

```
<div id="header">

             <img id="headerBackground" src="siteImages/tiltchair.jpg">

             <img id="Logo" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" align="middle" src="siteImages/final.png" alt="Logo">

             <img id="Text" align="middle" src="siteImages/TWText.png" alt="Logo">
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is how it can be done by using bootstrap. I would suggest you to read [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), to fully understand it through examples. There are lot of simple examples on their website, but [here](http://bootsnipp.com/) you can find plenty of bootstrap code snippets, that you can explore, and play with.

In this example below I distinguished parts of the code in purpose, so that you can easily read, the structure which was used for creating this modal. Some classes speak for itself: `modal-content, modal-header, modal-title, modal-body` and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> -->
    <title>Sign in modal form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <!-- This button below will trigger modal -->
        <p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOnoff">Click me!</button></p>
      </div>
   </div>



  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalOnoff" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lbOnoff">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="lbOnoff">Sign In</h4>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

              <form action="action_page.php">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-md btn-success btn-block" type='submit'>Login</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                  </div>
              </form>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The structure of modal form, was presented something like this:

- Button to trigger modal
- Modal content
- Modal header ( with text and close button )
- Modal Body ( with form )

I hope it helps

ref. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I do this it almost works in Chrome, with only the current menu tab showing the same behaviour. But in Safari it still displays the same way as is shown in the picture above, I have no idea what could be causing it. What do you think it could be?

Comment: Why don't you implement bootstrap modal? It is responsive and works in almost all major browsers. It is hard to tell what's going on with your code, because you just posted excerpt of it. If you want I can update my answer with bootstrap modal, and you find the way to implement it in your project?

Comment: That would be useful thank you. Its something I want to be able to make myself, but maybe looking at how the bootstrap modal is built can help me understand it.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer, you can see simple example using bootstrap. Try to understand the structure of modal, which will give you the better idea why your code example doesn't work properly. Cheers!